# How to change the font of default CodeIgniter form validation Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter form validation for my project.When the user don't fill the approprite value in text field then error is shown like "The Username field is required".so i want to change default font and style of this error in codeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set error delimeters with this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
```

And then you can style the div